aws code commit Pull request changes not visible
We have a few files in our project whose line count is around 4000-5000. i recently update 3 lines in one of such file and when i raised a PR, the changes in this were not visible. Is there a way to get such changes visible?



To view the file or the differences between the version of the file, you can open the file locally in your preferred IDE, use a Git diff tool, or run the git diff command.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-cs.html#troubleshooting-dd1

well isn't that too inconvenient : (
